# Nada acontece ao chamar arquivo .php via Ajax call em Javascript puro

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, phpmyadmin

Estou criando a persistência em servidor MySql para uma aplicação web minha.

Para isso estou usando o xampp e o phpmyadmin. Criei um banco no phpMyAdmin e na minha aplicação, em um javascript eu tenho uma requisição Ajax para um arquivo .php que faz essa comunicação com o servidor.

O que acontece é que, a função AjaxCall no meu .js é chamada, mas o arquivo Php passado pra ela com uma action, é simplesmente ignorado. Não acontece nada com o php. Coloquei echos no .php e nada aparece. Coloquei erros de sintaxe e o navegador nem acusou. Significa que o .php não está sendo acessado... Só que eu não não sei porque.

O meu Js:

```
function abreConta(){
    var cpf = document.getElementById('cpf').value;
    var agencia = document.getElementById('agencia').value;
    var conta = document.getElementById('conta').value;

    //As variáveis acima são preenchidas corretamente.

    parms = "&cpf"+cpf+"&agencia"+agencia+"&conta"+conta;
    ajaxCall("Persistencia.php?action=abreConta" +parms, mudaView);


}

function mudaView(listaParams){
    window.alert("Sua conta foi aberta com sucesso. Você será redirecionado ao menu inicial");
    mudaMenu("formularioDeAbertura", "menu1");
}


function ajaxCall(stringCall, callback){
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest;

    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
        if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
            console.log("Requisicao http em curso");
          callback(httpRequest.responseText);
        }
    }
    };
    httpRequest.open('GET', stringCall);
    httpRequest.send();
}
```

A pasta da minha aplicação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu Persistencia.php:

```
<?php

function conectaDB(){
    $con  =  mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","onbank");

    if(!$con){
        echo "<h2>Erro na conexao com a base dados...</h2>"; 
        echo "<h2> Erro " . mysqli_connect_errno() . ".</h2>";
        die();
    }
    $con->set_charset("utf8");
    return $con;
}


    if(@$_REQUEST['action'] == "abreConta")     //recupera lista de nomes das cidades
    {

        con = ConectaDB();
        $cpf = $con->real_escape_string($REQUEST['cpf']);
        $agencia = $con->real_escape_string($REQUEST['agencia']);
        $conta = $con->real_escape_string($REQUEST['conta']);

        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO contas (agencia,conta,dono) VALUES('$agencia','$conta', '$cpf');");]
        $con->close();

        //abreConta();
    }


    if(@_REQUEST['action'] == 'buscaContasCliente')
    {
        $cpf = buscaCpf();
        inicializaListaContas($cpf);

    }

    function buscaCpf(){
        $con = ConectaDB();
        $nome = $con->real_escape_string($REQUEST['nome']);

        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT cpf FROM clientes WHERE nome='$nome';");
        return $result;
    }
```

?>

Meu banco de dados no phpMyAdmin: Não está sendo alterado, devido ao Persistencia.php nao estar sendo executado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: a coluna saldo possui preenchimento automático com 0.

Na aba Network do f12 aparece o seguinte quando eu abro uma conta:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: porque a tag phpmyadmin? O que tem a ver com o problema?

Comment: Tá mostrando isso no console: `console.log("Requisicao http em curso");`?

Comment: Sim, isso mostra

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam tag phpMyAdmin? Aonde?  O phpmyadmin é onde tem o servidor mysql que eu to usando

Comment: O servidor de banco de dados não está no phpmyadmin, ele uma interface que você usa para acessar o bd. Use a tag do phpmyadmin quando o problema estiver relacionado a ele e não por que você usa ele para conferir se algo funcionou ou não

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você verificou o que está aparecendo no network do broswer? para verificar só precisa clicar em f12 e verificar a aba network. Depois realizar a requisição ajax. Deve aparecer um novo campo, nele provavelmente irá aparecer o erro no código PHP.

Ou você pode também acessar diretamente pelo broswer e verificar se tem algum erro. Nesse seu caso seria: http://localhost/Persistencia.php?action=abreConta. Deve aparecer melhor os erros que estão sendo retornados.

Recomendo também mudar a forma do request, hoje em javascript utilizamos uma forma mais simplificada para fazer Ajax no lado do javascript, veja um exemplo:

```
<script>

function abreConta(){

    let cpf = "cpf qualquer";
    let agencia = "agencia qualuqer";
    let conta = "conta qualquer";

    let params = "?cpf=" + cpf + "&agencia=" + agencia + "&conta=" + conta;

    ajaxCall(params, function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    });

}

function ajaxCall(params, callback){
    // Faz a requisicao HTTP para o servidor PHP
    fetch("ajax.php" + params)
        .then((response) => {
            alert("-- sucesso --");
        }).catch(() => alert("error"));
}

abreConta();

</script>
```

Esse é o PHP que está testando esse Javascript, fiz só como demostração:

```
<?php
$dados = [$_GET["cpf"], $_GET["conta"], $_GET["agencia"]];
echo json_encode($dados);
```

Quando descobrir qual erro que está dando no PHP você pode atualizar a pergunta se não conseguir resolver.

Comment: Descobri: Na opção "Response" do Network aponta o erro: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']' in C:\xampp\htdocs\AppGA\Persistencia.php on line 24

Comment: Consegui fazer a comunicação!! lol ; Só que a conta foi adicionada na tabela com os parâmetros todos zerados...

Comment: Agora bão retorna nenhum erro no response. Vou debugar com echos pra verificar onde os parâmetros não estão chegando.

Comment: Foi só na primeira tentativa, agora o MySQL está preenchendo as tabelas com todos os valores. Obrigado!!

Answer (score 1):

O erro está nesta linha:

```
parms = "&cpf"+cpf+"&agencia"+agencia+"&conta"+conta;
```

Faltam os sinais de igual `=` nos parâmetros:

```
             ↓               ↓                 ↓
parms = "&cpf="+cpf+"&agencia="+agencia+"&conta="+conta;
```

Sem os `=`, o PHP não está recebendo os valores.

Comment: Ah, entendi. Mas corrigi isso e não adiantou. Não mudou nada :(

Comment: Mas está mostrando o console.log na resposta do Ajax?

Comment: Coloque `console.log(httpRequest.responseText);` pra ver o que retorna.

Comment: Já tentou colocar um `echo "qualquer coisa";` no final do PHP, antes do `?>`?